# Disable form validation for a button ( Angular 4)

Tags: angular

I have a component which is loading in a dialog box (Material dialog) which contains few form fields.

Here is a markup of one field:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input [(ngModel)]="templatecategory.name" type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required #newName="ngModel" />
    <div *ngIf="newName.invalid && (newName.dirty || newName.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
      <div *ngIf="newName.errors.required">Name is required.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have two buttons on the model one is for save and next is cancel.

Here are those button markup:

```html
<div class="modal-footer"  mat-dialog-actions>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!newTemplateCategoryForm.form.valid">Save</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="onCancel();">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

But even when the Cancel button is pressed the form seems to be validating. How can I avoid this behavior?

Comment: Use [angular forms](https://angular.io/guide/forms). Pretty straightforward.

Comment: Yea.. Im also using Angular Forms. In that, may I know how can I accomplish the requested..

Comment: I think that the form is always validating. You can (click)="noshowerror=true;onCancel()" and not show error if the variable "noshowerror"==true. Don't forget turn the variable to false before show the form

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a pretty late answer, but I recently had the same problem and found this question.

The simplest solution would be to change the `<button>` that should not validate to a  `<a>`-tag. You still are able to use bootstrap or angular material to style the `<a>`-tag like a button, but you won't get the form validation errors.